# Use alternate syntax highlighting in middle of TextMate2 comment

Tags: regex, syntax-highlighting, text-editor, textmate2

By the very nature of a comment, this might not make sense.

On the other hand, what I'm trying to achieve is not too different from an escape character.

As a simple example, I want 
`# comment :break: comment` 
to show up more like like

```
#comment 
"break" 
# comment
```

would, but without the second `#`, everything is on the same line, and instead of quotes I have some other escape character. Although, like quotes (and unlike escape characters that I'm familiar with [e.g., `\`]), I intend to explicitly indicate the beginning and the end of the interruption to the comment.

Thanks to @Graham P Heath, I was able to achieve [alternate forms of comments in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32020469/different-syntax-highlighting-for-sub-types-of-comments). What I'm after is an enhancement to what was achieved there. In my scenario, `#` is a comment in the language I'm using (R), and `#'` functions both as an R comment and as the start of code in another language. Now, I can get everything after the `#'` to take on syntax highlighting that is different from the typical R comment, but I'm trying to get a very modest amount of syntax highlighting in this sub-language (`#'` actually indicates the start of markdown code, and I want the "raw" syntax highlighting for text surround in a pair of ` ).

The piece of the language grammar that I'm trying to interrupt is as follows:

```
{   begin = '(^[ \t]+)?(?=#'' )';
            end = '(?!\G)';
            beginCaptures = { 1 = { name = 'punctuation.whitespace.comment.leading.r'; }; };
            patterns = (
                {   name = 'comment.line.number-sign-tick.r';
                    begin = "#' ";
                    end = '\n';
                    beginCaptures = { 0 = { name = 'punctuation.definition.comment.r'; }; };
                },
            );
        },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure I've figured it out. What I didn't understand previously was how the scoping worked. I still don't understand it fully, but I now know enough to create nested definitions (regex) for the `begin` and `end` of each type of syntax.

The scoping makes things *so* much easier! Previously I wanted to do regex like `(?<=\A#'\s.*)(\$)` to find a dollar sign within the `#'`-style comment ... but obviously that won't work because of the repetition with `*` (`+` wouldn't work for the same reason). Via scoping, it's already implied that we have to be inside the `\A#'\s` match before `\$` will be matched.

Here is the relevant portion of my Language Grammar:

```
{   begin = '(^[ \t]+)?(?=#\'' )';
            end = '(?!\G)';
            beginCaptures = { 1 = { name = 'punctuation.whitespace.comment.leading.r'; }; };
            patterns = (

                {   name = 'comment.line.number-sign-tick.r';
                    begin = "#' ";
                    end = '\n';
                    beginCaptures = { 0 = { name = 'punctuation.definition.comment.r'; }; };


                    patterns = (

                        // Markdown within Comment
                        {   name = 'comment.line.number-sign-tick-raw.r';
                            begin = '(`)(?!\s)'; // backtick not followed by whitespace
                            end = '(?<!\s)(`)'; // backtick not preceded by whitespace
                            beginCaptures = { 0 = { name = 'punctuation.definition.comment.r'; }; };
                        },

                        // Equation within comment
                        {   name = 'comment.line.number-sign-tick-eqn.r';
                            begin = '((?<!\G)([\$]{1,2})(?!\s))';
                            end = '(?<!\s)([\$]{1,2})';
                            beginCaptures = { 0 = { name = 'punctuation.definition.comment.r'; }; };

                            // Markdown within Equation
                            patterns = (
                                {   name = 'comment.line.number-sign-tick-raw.r';
                                    begin = '(`)(?!\s)'; // backtick not followed by whitespace
                                    end = '(?<!\s)(`)'; // backtick not preceded by whitespace
                                    beginCaptures = { 0 = { name = 'punctuation.definition.comment.r'; }; };
                                },
                            );
                        },
                    );
                },

            );
        },
```

here is some R code:

```
# below is a `knitr` (note no effect of backticks) code chunk
#+ codeChunk, include=FALSE


# normal R comment, follow by code
data <- matrix(rnorm(6,3, sd=7), nrow=2)

#' This would be recognized as markdown by `knitr::spin()`, with the preceding portion as "raw" text
`note that this doesnt go to the 'raw' format ... it is normal code!`

#+ anotherChunk
# also note how the dollar signs behave normally
data <- as.list(data)
data$blah <- "blah"
`data`[[1]] # backticks behaving

#' I can introduce a Latex-style equation, filling in values from R using `knitr` code chunks: $\frac{top}{bottom}=\frac{`r topValue`}{`r botValue`}$ then continue on with markdown.
```

And here is what that looks like in TextMate2 after making these changes:
[image]

Pretty good, except the backticked pieces take on the italics when they're inside an equation. I can live with that. I can even convince myself that I wanted it that way ;) (by the way, I specified `fontName='regular'` for the courier new, so I don't know why that's getting overridden)